# how do i use the for instruction in the proposed line of code?

Tags: c, for-loop, integer, printf

who can assess here?

I need a step-by-step explanation of this program, in particular, I'm interested in this line of code:

```
for(i = n-((n+1) % 2); i>=1; i-=2)
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int i, n;
  scanf("%d",&n);
  for(i = n-((n+1) % 2); i>=1; i-=2)
  {
    if(i%2==1)
      printf("%d ", i);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please grab your beginner's C book and read the respective chapter. Then come back and [edit] your question, providing what you understand, and where in detail you stumble. For example, do you know how the `for` loop works? Do you know the operator `%`? And so on...

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment...?  [Debuggers](https://u.osu.edu/cstutorials/2018/09/28/how-to-debug-c-program-using-gdb-in-6-simple-steps/) are supremely useful for learning exactly what is happening while traversing  a mysterious piece of code.

Comment: `n-((n+1) % 2)` feels intentionally obfuscated. A statement like `n % 2 == 1 ? n : n - 1` meaning 'n if n is odd, otherwise n-1' might be easier to understand

Answer (score 1):

This expression

```
n-((n+1) % 2)
```

yields the closest odd number that is equal to or less than `n`.

For example if `n` is an even number for example is equal to `2` then the expression will be equal to the odd number `1`.
That is you will have in this case

```
2 - ( ( 2 + 1 ) % 2 )
```

that is equivalent to

```
2 - ( 3 % 2 )
```

that in turn is equivalent to

```
2 - 1
```

If `n` is an odd number for example equal to `3` then the expression will be equal to `3`.

So subtracting 2 as

```
i-=2
```

you will have always an odd number.

Thus this statement in the body of the for loop

```
if(i%2==1)
printf("%d ", i);
```

outputs positive odd numbers in the descending order.

For example if `n` is equal to `10` then `i` will be initially equal to `9` and the loop outputs

```
9 7 5 3 1
```

The if statement is redundant. You could just write

```
printf("%d ", i);
```